# Cauchy integral formula in proving equalities

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic on $D(0,R)$ s.t $|f(z)|<M$ for all $|z|<R$.
> Prove that $$|f^{(n)}(z)|\leq\dfrac{MRn!}{(R-|z|)^{n+1}},\quad n\geq0
>  ,\quad |z|<R.$$

My attempt:
For each $z\in D(0,R)$, take $0<r<R$ s.t $\overline{D}(z,r)\subset D(0,R)$.
Since $f$ is holomorphic on $ D(0,R)$, applying Cauchy integral formula, we have
$$f^{(n)}(z)=\dfrac{n!}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial D(z,r)}{}\dfrac{f(t)}{(t-z)^{n+1}}dt.$$
$\Rightarrow\quad |f^{(n)}(z)|\leq\dfrac{n!M}{2\pi}\int\limits_{\partial D(z,r)}\dfrac{dt}{r^{n+1}}$.
I'm stuck here, it seems not to work if I continue. Can someone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

$D(z,r)\subset D(0,R)$ implies $r<R-|z|$ so $\sup_{r<R-|z|}\frac1{r^{n+1}}=\frac1{(R-|z|)^{n+1}}$. Note $|\partial D(z,r)|\le 2\pi R$ we get $|f^{(n)}(z)|\le\frac{n!MR}{r^{n+1}}$ for all $r<R-|z|$. Taking supremum over all $r<R-|z|$ we get the inequality.

Comment: your solution is wrong, I'm afraid.

Comment: @AlexNguyen Sorry I didn't notice the code just then.